# Azure blob storage : token to share access

Tags: azure, token, blobstorage

we are creating a token to share access to a folder on azure blob storage.

In some cases the token is created with &sdd=1 at the end and in other cases not, I couldn't figure out why and I haven't found any documentation about it.

Can anyone tell me what this refers to?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> In some cases the token is created with &sdd=1 at the end and in other
> cases not, I couldn't figure out why and I haven't found any
> documentation about it.

`sdd` (short for `signedDirectoryDepth`) indicates the number of directories within the root folder of the directory specified in the canonicalizedResource field of the string-to-sign.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#construct-a-user-delegation-sas